# How can I organize already installed Android apps in groups (folders)?

Tags: android, homescreen, android-shortcut

I want to create folders or application groups on the Home Screen of an Android tablet for already installed apps.

The apps APK will be provided by someone external (I can't modify them). I need to create a script, a small app, or something similar that when executed look for the specific installed apps in the connected android device and then creates apps groups on the home screen.

For example, if I have 8 applications installed on the android device then I need to create 4 groups of 2 apps in each folder.

I'm totally new to Android developments although I have some experience with Java, any insight of where to start looking will be welcome.

The device Android version is 10.

I also was looking for an existing solution like [this APK Installer](https://apkinstaller.com/screenshots/), but it doesn't have the option to create the folder/groups.

Answer (score 0):

> I need to create a script, a small app, or something similar that when executed look for the specific installed apps in the connected android device and then creates apps groups on the home screen.

Android, the operating system, has no concept of "app groups". That is a feature of a launcher app. Some launcher apps may have APIs to allow third party apps to manipulate app groups, but the details would vary by launcher. On the whole, I expect very few launchers to have such an API. And, if you were expecting to be able to do this for arbitrary devies using arbitrary launcher apps... sorry, but that is not possible.

Comment: I want to do that for specific device models and a specific launcher. The default launcher for Android 10.

Comment: @Aikanáro: "The default launcher for Android 10" -- there is no default launcher for a version of Android. The pre-installed launcher app is determined by the device manufacturer. Users might install another launcher app and switch to using that.

Comment: What about installing a launcher that allows the apps reorganization? It doesn't matter if the user changes it later. @CommonsWare

Comment: @Aikanáro: "What about installing a launcher that allows the apps reorganization?" -- I cannot tell you if you are or are not allowed to install a launcher app on the device. Even if you are, you would need to find (or build) a launcher that supports app groups and supports some external way of manipulating what app groups exist and what apps are in those groups.